# Vote counts on questions regarding the Vox Populi badge

Tags: support, badges, voting

I voted 40 times today, but some of the votes were on questions instead of answers. At this point it blocks me from voting. It only shows me as having cast 32 votes, instead of 40. Is it because my question votes are 'not shown' or don't count as real votes, except for the daily limit, as the popup told me, due to downvotes on questions requiring 125 rep (1 more than I have)?

Then, should I avoid question votes for now as they appear to only count against the limit?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No, in order to vote as much as possible you should avoid *answer* votes instead. As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90734/295232):

> If 1 in 3 of your votes are on questions, you will get 40 votes.
>
> If you vote on fewer questions than that you will get fewer votes (lowest is 30).

Up- or downvotes doesn't matter.

Also, please vote because you appreciate the content. Don't vote just for the badges.

Comment: Curious: why is voting limited this way?

Comment: @NathanArthur it's described in [this blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/06/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/). TL;DR: without certain measures, voting tends to be skewed towards answers.

Comment: TBH, the wording of the badge itself challenges us to "Use the maximum 40 votes in a day"